# url RewriteEngine not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am tring to convert:

```
http://localhost/mysite/blog.php?slug=post-by-paritosh
```

To :

```
http://localhost/mysite/blog/post-by-paritosh
```

For that I am using .htaccess file with below rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*?)/?$ /blog.php?slug=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /blog\.php\?slug=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?blog\.php$ /blog/%1? [L,R=301]
```

After checking syntax on http://www.htaccesscheck.com/ I found that it is ok but the rewrite are not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this .htaccess inside `tgconnectmediaservice/` directory:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(tgconnectmediaservice/blog)\.php\?slug=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?blog/([^/]+)/?$ blog.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```